# do i need a transit visa in japan

Tags: japan, transit-visas, layovers, canadian-citizens

I'm a canadian citizen. i have a stopover to japan going home to canada and will transfer from tokyo HND airport to tokyo NRT.  Also, I have layover of from 4 am in the morning and be leaving at 6 pm of the same date.  I'm planning to have a 1 day sightseeing outside the airport.  Do I need to get a visa or any documents so i can go out?

Comment: The duplicate question is more aimed at people who usually need a visa for Japan.  However, as a Canadian citizen you don't need a visa, so you're free to enter Japan during transit.

Comment: Canadians don't need Japanese visas for short visits including transit and tourism.